# Would a native speaker append “no” to a statement to turn it into a question?

Tags: syntax, tag-questions

Does appending no to a statement make it a question?

E.g., "You decided to wait for me elsewhere than we had agreed, no?"

Note: The title and part of the body, as well as the idea, are taken verbatim from [this example question](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/41665/english-language-learners/41675#41675).

Comment: My perception is that ***non-native** speakers* are far more likely to use this form than natives. Probably because native speakers are more familiar with exactly which [question tag](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/3381/) to use in any given context, so they'd normally use that form.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As a native speaker I don't often find myself using *no* in this way, but sometimes I may attach *no* to the end of a statement to turn it into a question, especially if I'm expressing doubt.

There are, however, some situations where this wouldn't sound right and you would normally say something different. Some examples:

> But you arrived in town last night, *no*?

Is a good example of where the appending of *no* works. But, to me, it is more natural to say something like:

> But didn't you arrive in town last night?
>
> **or:**
>
> But you arrived in town last night, didn't you?

Another example:

> She was on her way to work, *no*?
>
> **Sounds better as:**
>
> She was on her way to work, wasn't she?

"*..., right?*" can also be used to express doubt and can be a better indication to the person you're talking to that you are asking them a question and would like a response. For example:

> You took the ferry, right?
>
> He had a lot to eat, right?

Answer (score 0):

I don’t normally see ‘no’ attached at the end of an interrogative statement. But I’ve seen some people using it informally. I wonder if this style is even acceptable in written English?

Here’s a link from grammar girl on how to format a question

http://grammar.quickanddirtytips.com/punctuating-questions.aspx