# Which verb is best to make a question-tag from?

Tags: tag-questions

I want to ask about two sentences, and what would be the correct way to form a question:

- It's very important that we eat healthy food, ...........?

  Which would be the correct question tag: (isn't it) or (don't we)?
- It's a must that all applicants follow the rules of the competition, ..........?

  Which would the correct question tag: (don't they) or (mustn't they)?

Please could you tell me the correct answers, and, more importantly, why those are correct?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For the first example, *isn't it* is correct. *Don't we* does not make sense in this context. The sentence should be:

> It's very important that we eat healthy food, isn't it?

The second example, I would not use either option. Instead, I would use *isn't it* here as well:

> It's a must that all applicants follow the rules of the competition, isn't it?

The reasoning for this is that it coincides with the beginning of the sentence. For example, I might use any of these:

> They should eat healthy food, shouldn't they?
>
> There are a lot of people here, aren't there?
>
> You are connected to the Internet, aren't you?

*Don't* and *didn't* are exceptions to this:

> You have an Internet connection, don't you?
>
> He came to work yesterday, didn't he?

Answer (score 3):

As other answers indicate, it's quite straightforward that in these specific cases, the only acceptable "question tag" is ***isn't it?*** It would be much more incisive (and more awkward) if OP's example had been:

> *It's important that we **should** eat healthy food, ...........?*

That still wouldn't change the fact that technically speaking, ***isn't it*** is still the only "correct" tag, but in practice many/most native speakers wouldn't see anything odd about using ***shouldn't we*** there.

As an example of how ridiculous things can become when people try to force "strictly logical" constraints on the "subject" of a question tag, consider [this sentence](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=zC5BDVm683UC&pg=PA181&dq=%22that%20he%20should%22%20%22shouldn%27t%20he%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=O5wyUa-wItKV0QWRwYGYAQ&ved=0CDsQ6AEwAg#v=onepage&q=%22that%20he%20should%22%20%22shouldn%27t%20he%22&f=false):

> *All I meant was that he should have seen it, shouldn't he?”*

Those very same "strict rules" that require ***isn't it*** for OP's example would force us to accept that the only valid tag for my example must be ***didn't I***. It probably wouldn't raise an eyebrow among native speakers if you did use the "valid" form, but unquestionably the version as written would be far more common.

---

In short, there *is* a vague area hereabouts, since *meaning* affects question tag format as much as, if not more than "grammatical rules". In most cases, the question tag agrees with the initial subject/verb. But if there's a more semantically significant "secondary" possibility, it's often acceptable to target that instead.

Comment: But I want to know if the choice in the second question is only between (don't they) and (mustn't they) which of them should I choose in the exam?, I understood that both are wrong but which is more correct?

Comment: @Sohail: I find it hard to believe any examiner would ask you to choose the "least bad" of two "invalid" alternatives. They are both *totally* unacceptable, so far as I'm concerned, since the only credible tag for your #2 is ***isn't it?*** But I suppose I must admit that *don't they* more strongly implies a non-native speaker, whereas feasibly a not-very-articulate native Anglophone might come out with *mustn't they*.

Answer (score 1):

In the first sentence, it should be

> It's very important that we eat healthy food, **isn't it**?

One problem is that the subject of the first clause "it" does not specify what "it" is, though it should say in context. If you say

> **To stay healthy**, it's very important that we eat healthy food, **isn't it**?

Since we are talking about health, its a state, not an action. So "isn't it" is appropriate.

In the second sentence, again it depends on what "it" is. If you say

> **In this competition**, it's a must that all applicants follow the rules of the competition, **isn't it**?

"Competition" is an event but not an action, so "don't they" or "mustn't they" are incorrect.